# How to install LDR version of Microsoft Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-update, .net-framework, installer

I need a sos.dll version 4.0.30319.544 and as far as I have found the only way to get one - replay the installation process of .Net framework from the beginning. I have a brand new VM with .Net framework and now I need to install [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2604121) update.

The problem is - when  I install it - I end up with version 4.0.30319.269 from GDR Service Branch, not 4.0.30319.544 from LDR Service Branch.

Is there any way to get the LDR version?

I have found a few instructions using PowerShell and even one [.Net project](https://ldrinstaller.codeplex.com/), but they rely on .mum file being present and it is not in the specified update.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it!!!

First, thanks to WindowsWiki for [this post](http://www.windowswiki.info/2009/02/19/how-to-extract-msumspmsiexe-files-from-the-command-line/) where I got the commands:

```
msix patch.msp /out C:<target_dir>
expand -F:* update.cab C:<target_dir>
```

But the msix is not a default utility, so I had to google for it. Got it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/04/07/571138.aspx). ([direct link](http://sdrv.ms/QXFXhr)).

So the final command I had to run:

1. Run the `NDP40-KB2604121-x64.exe`, it will unpack the contents to temprorary folder (`C:\3ec161398e4e56a1c7cee1457a295e` in my case)
2. Copy them to `C:\1`
3. Download msix and run smth like `C:\msix\Release\MsiX.exe NDP40-KB2604121-x64.msp /out C:\1`. You will end up with 2 `.cab` files and some other files.
4. Run `expand -F:* QFEGDR.cab C:\1\2` and you will get the files (`sos_dll_amd64` in my case)